# Extract timestamp from column with T and Z

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

I have some logs in BigQuery which contain timestamps stored in this format :

```
2022-08-12T17:00:39.615375452Z
2022-08-12T17:00:46.166243682Z
2022-08-12T10:00:54.089419181Z
2022-08-12T07:35:39.581949967Z
2022-08-12T07:00:49.781439084Z  
2022-08-12T09:00:18.66496629Z
2022-08-12T07:38:48.435754277Z  
2022-08-12T15:00:23.25020843Z
```

If I try to convert the column to timestamp, using the `TIMESTAMP` function, I get this error :

```
Invalid timestamp: '2022-08-10T16:00:05.909896168Z'
```

I bypassed this error by manually extracting the desired fields, but this is not very elegant and would like to know if there is another way of doing that.

Thanks !

Comment: **SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E*SZ', '2022-08-10T16:00:05.909896168Z')** doesn't work?

Comment: It does work, I was not aware of the correct syntax to use. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @jaytiger, try using:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E*SZ', '2022-08-10T16:00:05.909896168Z')
```